# Drawing Bubbles in Android Studio Java

Tags: java, android-studio, object, bitmap, android-bitmap

I'm building a game for my Android app studio class, and the game's objective is to pop the bubbles. I currently have 7 bubble textures installed in the game and set up under the Bubble.java file (See Below) in the Gameview.java file I have the game generating the bubbles and then moving them down. I followed a tutorial to get the game to this point and have been trying to modify it to generate the other 6 bubbles, but the most I can get it to do is have the bubbles blink each frame through the different textures as they move down the screen. All the bubbles are the same X & Y of 200

I removed all imports for simplicity of the files.

```
public class Bubble {
    Bitmap bubble[] = new Bitmap[7];
    int bubbleFrame = 0;
    int bubbleX, bubbleY, bubbleV;
    Random random;

    public Bubble(Context context){
        bubble[0] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.bubble0);
        bubble[1] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.bubble1);
        bubble[2] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.bubble2);
        bubble[3] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.bubble_green);
        bubble[4] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.bubble_blue);
        bubble[5] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.bubble_yellow);
        bubble[6] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.bubble_red);
        random = new Random();
        resetPosition();
    }

    public Bitmap getBubble(int bubbleFrame){
        return bubble[bubbleFrame];
    }

    public int getBubbleWidth(){
        return bubble[0].getWidth();
    }

    public int getBubbleHeight(){
        return bubble[0].getHeight();
    }

    public void resetPosition() {
        bubbleX = random.nextInt(GameView.dWidth - getBubbleWidth());
        bubbleY = -200 + random.nextInt(600) * -1;
        bubbleV = 35 + random.nextInt(16);
    }

}
```

Here is my Gameview file as well.

```
public class GameView extends View {

    Bitmap background, ground, player;
    Rect rectBackground, rectGround;
    Context context;
    Handler handler;
    final long UPDATE_MILLIS = 30;
    Runnable runnable;
    Paint textPaint = new Paint();
    Paint healthPaint = new Paint();
    float TEXT_SIZE = 120;
    int points = 0;
    int life = 30;
    static int dWidth, dHeight;
    Random random;
    float playerX, playerY;
    float oldX;
    float oldPlayerX;
    ArrayList<Bubble> bubbles;
    ArrayList<Pop> pops;

    public GameView(Context context){
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.background0);
        ground = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ground);
        player = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.player);
        Display display = ((Activity) getContext()).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        dWidth = size.x;
        dHeight = size.y;
        rectBackground = new Rect(0,0,dWidth,dHeight);
        rectGround = new Rect(0,dHeight - ground.getHeight(), dWidth, dHeight);
        handler = new Handler();
        runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                invalidate();
            }
        };
        textPaint.setColor(Color.rgb(255,165,0));
        textPaint.setTextSize(TEXT_SIZE);
        textPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
        textPaint.setTypeface(ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.bubblegum));
        healthPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        random = new Random();
        playerX = dWidth / 2 - player.getWidth() / 2;
        playerY = dHeight - ground.getHeight() - player.getHeight();
        bubbles = new ArrayList<>();
        pops = new ArrayList<>();
        // Add First Bubble to game
        Bubble bubble = new Bubble(context);
        bubbles.add(bubble);
    }

    // Draw Game
    @Override
    protected void onDraw (Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawBitmap(background, null, rectBackground, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(ground, null, rectGround, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(player, playerX, playerY, null);

        // Draw Bubbles
        for (int i=0; i<bubbles.size(); i++){
            canvas.drawBitmap(bubbles.get(i).getBubble(bubbles.get(i).bubbleFrame), bubbles.get(i).bubbleX, bubbles.get(i).bubbleY, null);
            bubbles.get(i).bubbleY += bubbles.get(i).bubbleV;

            // Bubble Collision Detection with Ground - Remove Lives.
            if (bubbles.get(i).bubbleY + bubbles.get(i).getBubbleHeight() >= dHeight - ground.getHeight()){
                //life --;
                Pop pop = new Pop(context);
                pop.popX = bubbles.get(i).bubbleX;
                pop.popY = bubbles.get(i).bubbleY;
                pops.add(pop);
                bubbles.get(i).resetPosition();
                
                //Check for Life 0
                if (life == 0){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, GameOver.class);
                    intent.putExtra("points", points);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                    ((Activity) context).finish();
                }
            }
        }

        // Player Collision Detection with Bubble - Add Points.
        for (int i=0; i < bubbles.size(); i++){
            if (bubbles.get(i).bubbleX + bubbles.get(i).getBubbleWidth() >= playerX
                    && bubbles.get(i).bubbleX <= playerX + player.getWidth()
                    && bubbles.get(i).bubbleY + bubbles.get(i).getBubbleWidth() >= playerY
                    && bubbles.get(i).bubbleY + bubbles.get(i).getBubbleWidth() <= playerY + player.getHeight()){
                points += 10;

                // Add more bubbles based on Points value
                if (points % 400 == 0 || points == 50 || points == 100 || points == 200){
                    Bubble bubble = new Bubble(context);
                    bubbles.add(bubble);
                }
                Pop pop = new Pop(context);
                pop.popX = bubbles.get(i).bubbleX;
                pop.popY = bubbles.get(i).bubbleY;
                pops.add(pop);
                bubbles.get(i).resetPosition();
            }
        }

        // Remove Pop image after bubble is popped.
        for (int i=0; i<pops.size(); i++){
            canvas.drawBitmap(pops.get(i).getPop(pops.get(i).popFrame), pops.get(i).popX,
                    pops.get(i).popY, null);
            pops.get(i).popFrame++;
            if (pops.get(i).popFrame > 0){
                pops.remove(i);
            }
        }

        // Player health bar
        if (life == 2){
            healthPaint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        } else if (life == 1) {
            healthPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        }
        canvas.drawRect(dWidth-200, 30, dWidth-200+60*life, 80, healthPaint);
        canvas.drawText("" + points, 20, TEXT_SIZE, textPaint);
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, UPDATE_MILLIS);
    }

    // Player movement through touch input.
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float touchX = event.getX();
        float touchY = event.getY();
        if (touchY >= playerY){
            int action = event.getAction();
            if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                oldX = event.getX();
                oldPlayerX = playerX;
            }
            if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
                float shift = oldX - touchX;
                float newPlayerX = oldPlayerX - shift;
                if (newPlayerX <= 0)
                    playerX = 0;
                else if (newPlayerX >= dWidth - player.getWidth())
                    playerX = dWidth - player.getWidth();
                else
                    playerX = newPlayerX;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```